# Powering RD-ZD-25 DC 110V 50W bread machine motor?

Tags: power-supply

I have a RD-ZD-25 DC 110V 50W bread machine motor that I'd like to use on a ball mill project but I can't find what sort of power it needs. Am I safe to assume it wants 110V DC?

EDIT (by jonk) to add sample pictures from [ReduceScrapping.com](https://www.reducescrapping.com/Complete-Machines-/2000-and-up-/Cook-County-/Used-/3D10-motor-rd-zd-25-110VDC-50W-from-toastmaster-bread.do):

[image]
[image]

Comment: No, you cannot assume that the power rating of the *appliance* applies to the components inside.  You'll have to examine the motor (it may have a nameplate...) or determine how the appliance powered it.

Comment: it makes no financial sense to design a DC motor into an AC powered appliance

Comment: @jsotola actually it does when the application calls for it.  The motor in a bread machine doesn't just spin, and it doesn't ramp up and down or sound like a gear motor would.  Rather it abruptly and violently kneads and throws the dough.  Its vaguely possible today you could do it with a crude version of an AC servomotor (or more likely a brushless DC one), but those are going to take more drive electronics than a permanent magnet brush motor.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks ... I learn something new every day ... time to disassemble a breadmaker ... lol

Answer (score 1):

The sticker says 110V DC, and it's got brushes and a commutator.  So, yes.

As mentioned in the comments, it's for a bread machine that needs to start and stop suddenly, so it'll probably even handle momentary overload without damaging the magnets.

Pay attention to that "50W" rating, though -- that means no more than 50W / 100V \$\simeq\$ 0.45A.  Monitor the current when you first commission your machine & make sure you're not violating that, or use a 1/2A slow-blow fuse.

Comment: Is it possible to give it less voltage? Does it need to be a nice clean DC or if I use a crude power supply will it be OK. I am going to guess it would be fine with "dirty" DC. Thanks!

Comment: The 110VDC is the maximum rating.  You can always give it less -- and should, if it's hitting 0.45A.  The other maximum rating is current, which you need to infer from the 50W and the 110VDC -- hence, 0.45A.